# Deploying HTML templates with Angular 2

Tags: angular, webpack

I have a web application and one of the requirements is to make the HTML easily customizable by customers. If I'm required to bundle the HTML up in a javascript file, this isn't going to be the easiest thing for our customers to edit and would most likely require deploying the source so they could modify and build.

I realize I can deploy the entire code base as-is, but that also means giving up all kinds of performance. Ideally I would like to bundle all of the javascript but have the HTML templates deployed separately where they are easily accessible. Is this model possible with Angular?

Comment: So every component's template would be another HTTP GET away? The performance hit would be pretty huge. Not to mention the customer would have to know about things like Angular's templating syntax, what fields are exposed to the template and how the CSS encapsulation works. Are you sure Angular is the tool for this job?

Comment: If only some of the HTML needs to be customizable, is it possible to do with data? For example, if they want their company name to appear at the top, have a configuration file that allows them to specify their company name and use data binding to that configuration file. Would something like that work?

Comment: You could also look at using dynamic component loading: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-component-loader.html

Comment: @jonrsharpe I agree it's not ideal, and you're right - Angular might just be the wrong tool for this job and I'm just hell bent on trying to make it work. I think I may need to reevaluate.

Comment: @DeborahK Thank you! This is something I had considered and it might be a solution since the customizations only really take place in specific areas of the application. I will read up on dynamic component loading. Thanks for the link.